# n - level deep mutable copy of any object in objective C

Tags: ios, iphone

looking for n - level deep mutable copy

not taking about deep copying of only upper level element or 2nd level elements, 
looking for dynamic solution up to n-level elements.

don't want to traverse through each level and then make mutable copy of it and replace it.

most of the mutable copy solutions works up to 1-2 levels.

Comment: I am not getting the purpose here.

Comment: So levels beyond level-n will be shallow copied?  Sounds like a strange request.

Comment: What kind of classes are you talking about? Each of your custom class should override the mutableCopy method in which it returns its mutable version copy with all bound objects (such as properties) being copied to mutable version as well. By doing so you have a N level mutable copy.